# how to get children array of an element in jquery

Tags: jquery

Heres my element, i want to arrange the children inside it by looping through them.

```
<div id="animDummy1">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Heres how i imagine the code should look but children(), of course, doesn't return an array of the children

```
var children=$('#animDummy1').children();
for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++){
    children[i].css('left',i*120+'px');
}
```

The question - can i get children array for use in a loop? I know i can attach a function for each of children to be executed on, but can i get that increasing "i" in there?

Thnx.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`children()` returns a jQuery object of the children which resembles an array of DOM nodes. Your problem is inside the loop - when you access individual objects with `[]` you get back plain DOM nodes which don't have a `css` method. Either use `.eq(i)` or `$(children[i])`.

Or just use the [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method, which lets you do the same without having to write a for loop by hand. Read the docs to find out how to get the index of the element inside the callback.

Comment: This isn't really correct - `children()` returns a jQuery object not an array. It does have "indexes" that can be used by jQuery.each(), but it's not of type array. Try using `children().toArray()` if you'd like to get an actual array. To confirm this, try out `children() instance of Array` vs `children().toArray() instanceof Array` :)

Comment: @Jason: Fine, I guess my language wasn't 100% exact.

Answer (score 13):

This is the correct way.

```
var children=$('#animDummy1').children();

children.each(function(idx, val){
   $(this).css('left',idx*120+'px');
});
```

or actually this is better.

```
$('#animDummy1').children().each(function(idx, val){
   $(this).css('left',idx*120+'px');
})
```

Comment: And where is "i" being defined/increased?

Comment: Need to define the i variable.  Should be function(i), or define it in the function.

Answer (score 8):

The other answers to use jQuery's `children().each()` are likely helpful for most cases. However, if you do need an actual javascript Array, you can do the following:

```
var childrenArray = $('#animDummy1').children().toArray();
```

This would allow you have a real array for use in a loop or with other functions that require an array as a parameter.

Comment: Most helpful answer for my situation where I simply needed JS arrays to use with concat()

Answer (score 4):

`children()` returns a set of jQuery objects and `children[i(anyNumber)]` will return the dom element. So calling `css` jQuery method on dom element will through an error. You should use `eq` method if you want to access any particular element at a given index. Try this.

```
var children = $('#animDummy1').children();
for(var i = 0;i < children.length;i++){
    children.eq(i).css('left', (i*120+'px') );
}
```

`.eq()` reference: http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 4):

Many jQuery methods let you pass a function directly in place of the new value you want assigned.

For your example...

```
$('#animDummy1').children().css('left', function(i, curr_left) {
    return i * 120;
});
```

---

So here I called `.css()` directly on the `.children()` set, and instead of a number for the `'left'` value, I gave a function.

The function is invoked once for each element. The parameters represent the index of the current iteration, and the current css value of the current element in the iteration.

The `return` value of the function will be used as the value to set on the current element.

Comment: That is pretty sweet.  I did not know I could do it that way!

Comment: @thenetimp: Yeah, it can be pretty convenient. Quite a few jQuery functions have this option.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for me

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var children = $('#animDummy1').children();        

    $(children).each(function(index, item){                 
        console.log(index);            
    });           
});
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/eGQyD/)

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery:

.each() get allow to each index of array with childrens of $('#someObject'):

```
$('#animDummy1').each(function(index, item) {
   // Do Something with each $(item) children of #animDummy with index
});
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Little touch and code is working.

```
var children=$('#animDummy1').children().toArray();

var children=$('#animDummy1').children();
for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++){
    $(children[i]).css('left',i*120+'px');
}
```

Your code is ok except  **$(children[i])** and  define children as array with **.toArray()**

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(function () {
        var sortOrder = [3, 4, 1, 5,2];
        var onLoad = $('#parentDiv>p').get();
        for (var i = 0; i < onLoad.length; i++) {
            var inRearranging = $('#parentDiv>P').get();
            var orderingID = "#paragraph" + sortOrder[i];
            $(orderingID).insertBefore("#" + inRearranging[i].id);
        }
    });



<div id="parentDiv">
    <p id="paragraph1">1</p>
    <p id="paragraph2">2</p>
    <p id="paragraph3">3</p>
    <p id="paragraph4">4</p>
    <p id="paragraph5">5</p>
</div>
```